# How to write Response.redirect with Query_string server variables in ASP

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, server-variables

I'm trying to redirect users to my mobile page equivalent of a desktop page. Right now I can only get them to the home page.

```
If b.test(u) or v.test(Left(u,4)) then response.redirect("/mobile.asp") End If
```

I'd like to redirect to the mobile page with the additional correct variables. So the redirect response should be to `"/mobile.asp?m=here"` from the `"/home.asp?m=here"` page and `"/mobile.asp?m=there"` from the `"/home.asp?m=there"` etc.

I can get the variables with `<% Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")) %>` but my syntax must be off when I try to concat the redirect

```
If b.test(u) or v.test(Left(u,4)) then response.redirect("/mobile.asp?&Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))&""") End If
```

Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `response.write` in there. Something like this (not tested it though)

`response.redirect("/mobile.asp?" & Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))`

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to mark the question answered when you can :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to put something dynamic into your string it has to be determinated first, then use a `&` to concatenate other strings / variables. So you want your code to look like this:

```
If b.test(u) or v.test(Left(u,4)) then response.redirect("/mobile.asp?" & Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))) End If
```

also, you should check for any query strings to know weather to put the `?` or not.